# Regarding sculpt model

Tags: sculpting

My 1st question regarding sculpting. Im learning on sculpt modelling need information and help. We paint on 2d surface and make the bump and its on the 3d mesh. If it is simple like lines we or circle we can draw easily. If the design is complicated and repeating way then how it is used. This is the reference image below.

[image]

I want to know like we design in illustrator or coreldraw or gimp and make use svg file and import and use the complicated design. I want to know with svg file can we do sculpting. How it works here in sculpt mode. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: Svg files are vector images, they are imported as curves from what you can get the geometry of the reliefs. So it's basically importing the edges that can help you **modeling** true shapes. You can also export your files as raster images (so we are not talking about svg anyomore) and use them as "bump maps", but this is something realted to **texturing/shading**. Could you clarify which one of the two ways are you following? What exactly your question is?

Comment: @Carlo Thanks for replying. I just want the design which i have made in svg format with the paint sculpt mode. The above design of the flower and the array . How can i make the above flower and array of it